# sbpl on Hydro compilation error

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, sbpl, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all.

I just compiled `navigation_experimental-hydro-devel` with catkin-make in ROS hydro. However, it does not compile due to changes in `costmap2d`.

Just wondering if there might be any patches or some solution to make sbpl compile in hydro.

In advance thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173343/sbpl-on-hydro-compilation-error/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2014-06-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2014-06-30**:
Hi, thank you very much for your answer, I have solved the issues with unicycleplussidewaysplusbackturn.mprim, however I have another issue, Sometimes it get stuck when it gets trap in inflated obstacles even though there is enough space around the robot.

I found the package sbpl_recovery in this site thttps://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_experimental/tree/hydro-devel/sbpl_recovery  hat I think it could help to recover when the robot gets trap. But the package does compile under Hydro due to changes in costmap2d. Or is there some other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Johannes Meyer and I both have branches of the sbpl_lattice_planner that compile and run on Hydro:

- Johannes's: https://github.com/meyerj/sbpl_lattice_planner
- Mine: https://github.com/trainman419/sbpl_lattice_planner

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2014-06-11**:
Thank you very much, I download it and then I could compile it under hydro, just one question; is it possible to test the package with the launch file  `sbpl_lattice_planner move_base_sbpl_fake_localization_2.5cm.launch` or in other words, how can I test the package?

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2014-06-11**:
Or maybe you may have a launch file to take a look at it :), I mean how to include sbpl_lattice_planner in the navigation stack

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-11**:
My application and the setup is a little bit messy. I don't really have time to explain it, but my top-level launch file is https://github.com/trainman419/dagny_nav/blob/master/dagny_nav_launch/dagny_nav.launch .

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2014-06-11**:
thank you very much, however dont you need some hoe run the package "sbpl_lattice_planner"   or where you get <param name="SBPLLatticePlanner/primitive_filename"?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-11**:
I don't have time to explain it. Go read the nav stack docs.

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2014-06-12**:
@acp: You need to set "base_global_planner" parameter to "SBPLLatticePlanner" - planner will be loaded at runtime. It's same as with other planners - you don't need to run them separately. See this: https://github.com/trainman419/dagny_nav/blob/master/dagny_nav_launch/dagny_nav.yaml

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2014-09-17**:
@acp: i also compiled that stack with catkin_make in  hydro, got two errors.  (no exist SBPLLatticePlannerStats.h and changes in costmap2d),how do you clean those files   built by   catkin_make navigation_experimental-hydro-devel ,and  downloaded "Johannes's"or "ahendrix's" to catkin_make??